# Exit all subs in that button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button that runs several subs one after another:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.Run ("sub1") 
    Application.Run ("sub2") 
    Application.Run ("sub3")  
    Application.Run ("sub4")      
End Sub
```

I have checks in each subs that check if a file that is to be opened exists, if yes, it goes on, if no, it `Exit Sub`s. But the problem is, it exits only the current sub, but all the next are being executed which might result in a mess.

Is there a way to exit all the subsequent subs?

Comment: change them to being functions, then have a Boolean return, then you can say `if sub1 then if sub2 then if sub3.....`  http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html   Your Boolean would be set by the file opened exists for example

Comment: Turn the subs into a functions then you can return a boolean flag whether they completed or not; you can then test for this before running the next function

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Wouldn't it require significant edits in code? Functions are supposed to return values and act differently from subs.

Comment: do you not want to make any changes? it would require an additional line and a signature change from `sub x` to `function x as Boolean`

Comment: What are sub1, sub2, sub3 and sub4? There's several ways to go about this, but since it's not clear what you're actually doing, it's hard to suggest a best solution.

Comment: You could use the [`End` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/end-statement), but I'd probably not recommend that.

Comment: Or you could check  whether file exists *before* you invoke the subroutine that depends on that file... that is the correct way to do it. Validate your inputs *ahead* of the process(es), when possible.

Comment: @David Zemens `sub1` and the rest are subs.

Comment: @David Zemens Do you mean create another command button with a single subroutine that tells if files exist or not?

Comment: Yeah I know they are subroutiens, but what are their contents? Please see [ask] and consider providing [mcve] to illustrate your specific problem. Otherwise, it is not clear what is the best solution for your problem(s).

Comment: @ Nathan_Sav I changed subs to functions but not sure what to do else. I can set a boolean at a sub's start and then make `function=that boolean` and then in command button `variable = func()` and pass that variable to other subs that are to be run. But `Application.run` doesn't return any variables even with functions, does it?

Comment: I don't know why this would have to be from "another" command button, then again, I don't know what you're doing because you haven't shown your code.

Answer (score 2):

An example

```
if sub1 then sub2
```

using a function like so, the last one can remain as a sub

```
public function sub1() as Boolean

dim blnFileExists as Boolean

....file checking

sub1=blnFileExists

if blnFileExists then exit function

....go on

end function
```

Comment: I don't have any problem with exiting a function, or a sub. My problem is in exiting the command button with the rest of the subs that will be run otherwise.

Comment: Which is explained in the 1st line.  I think you should accept some of the suggestions and do a little research/some work, as you realised that this solution and other comments are not working in less than 1 minute.

Comment: But whole quiestion was about how exit a button, because I can already exit the sub. If you don't provide any details on how to exit the button, what's the point?

Comment: Exactly `if sub1 then if sub2 then if sub3 then if sub4 then sub5`  if sub1 returns false, no others will run, leaving you at  CommandButton2's exit sub.  Do you know of the IF statement?

Comment: FWIW I don't like this solution, because it artificially turns *procedures* into functions, using the "error return value" paradigm, which forces the caller to always verify the return value, which is contrary to the idea of structured error handling promoted with the `On Error` and `Err.Raise` statements. If the error path is truly *exceptional*, the procedure should *raise an error* ("throw an exception" in other languages), not return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

> if yes, it goes on, if no, it `Exit Sub`s.

In all cases, your procedures completed successfully, as far as the caller is concerned.

Seems like a case of "let it bubble up" to me. I presume you procedures look something like this:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    'do stuff
CleanExit:
    'clean up resources
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    'handle error (?)
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

So the caller has no way of knowing whether the operation succeeded or not.

If it doesn't make much sense to make them return a `Boolean` indicating success (i.e. turning them into `Function` procedures and returning `False` on error - which is NOT always a good solution, *especially* if the error path is truly *exceptional*), then the other solution is to *not* let the "happy path" carry on:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    'do stuff
CleanExit:
    'clean up resources
    With Err
        If .Number <> 0 Then .Raise .Number, "DoSomething", .Description
    End With
End Sub
```

Now your calling code gets to know what happened (you could raise custom errors, include the procedure as the `Source`, etc.), and can act accordingly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    DoSomething
    DoSomethingElse
    DoAnotherThing
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    With Err
        MsgBox "Error " &  & .Number & " in " & .Source & ": " & .Description, vbExclamation 
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's what worked for me:

```
Function sub1()
     ...
     Dim result As Boolean
     result=True
     If (fileThereIs = False) Then
             result=False
     End If


    ...
    sub1=result
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim fileCheck As Boolean
    fileCheck = Application.Run("sub1")
    If (fileCheck = True) Then
         Application.Run ("sub2") 
         Application.Run ("sub3")  
         Application.Run ("sub4")      
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How is that different to what I and others have said?